# How to get multible span content -Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

[Here is the target html codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYOUP.png)

I'm planing to make a typing bot and i should get all words inside all spans "see the image link above".

I tried:

```
words = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='row1']//span")
for word in words:
    print(word.text)
```

Any Help?

Comment: please format your html as text - we cant copy and paste images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   words = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='row1']//span")
```

use elements not element. You are using element which returns webelemnt and not a list

Comment: @JRazor why it doesn't he is using element which returns webelemnt and not a list

Comment: If I understand you well you mean it should return a list?

Comment: @amjdalqasemy yes then only you can iterate over it , like in your qeustion . That comment was for someont else

Comment: yeah, then you should use for loop like:  [print(word.text) for word in words]. it works fine with me